# Keyboard shortcut difficulty with RSTudio on Windows 10

Tags: r, rstudio

I am a mac user, but two of my students were running RStudio in class today and when they tried to Ctrl+Alt+R to compile their R-script, HP Recovery Manage pops up.

How can I help them fix this problem?

D.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be uninstalling, killing or otherwise altering HP Recovery Manage. If you can't alter HP Recovery Manage [customisation of keyboard shortcuts is currently supported by the preview release of RStudio.](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178-Customizing-Keyboard-Shortcuts)

Otherwise they could:

- select all (`Ctrl + A`) then run selection (`Ctrl + enter`),
- run their code via the tool bars by going `code > run region > run all`.